# C++ can't access field from inherited class

Tags: c++, class

Hello guys a have a problem, that i can't access field tablica[i]->help, in generuj function, its saying that this field is not existing in class Task.
How can i achieve it ?

```
class Task
{
  protected:
     string contents;
     int id_pyt;
     int nr_pyt;
};

class Task4Answ : public Task
{
private:
    int help;
public:
    Task4Answ(string contents1, int id,int nr,int help1)
    {
        contents=contents1;
        id_pyt=id;
        nr_pyt=nr;
        help=help1;
    }
};

class TaskCollection
{
    protected:
        Task *collection[60];
    public:
        friend class Generator;
        TaskCollection()
        {
          collection[0] = new Task4Answ("Ile jest por roku w Polsce? \na) 1 \nb) 2 \nc) 3 \nd) 4",1,0);
          collection[1] = new Task4Answ("Kto wygral tegoroczny Roland Garros? \na) Federer \nb) Djokovic \nc) Nadal \nd) Thiem",1,1);
class Generator
{
protected:
    Task *tablica[10];
    TaskCollection T1;
public:
    Generator(){}
    void Generuj()
    {
            if(T1.collection[x]->id_pyt==1)
            {
                tablica[i]=new Task4Answ("0",0,0);
                tablica[i]->contents=T1.collection[x]->contents;
                tablica[i]->id_pyt=T1.collection[x]->id_pyt;
                tablica[i]->nr_pyt=T1.collection[x]->nr_pyt;
                tablica[i]->help=T1.collection[x]->help; //here is the problem
            }
        }
    }
```

Or maybe there is some other solution of the project im doing now.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The `Task` type has no `help` member.

Comment: It looks like `tablica` is an array of `Task`s, but `help` is defined in `Task4Answ`.

Comment: 1) `help` does not exist in `Task`, it exists in `Task4Answ`.  2) Even if it did, `help` is private so you would not be able to access it anyway.  You probably want to make `help` a function: `/* In Task */ virtual int getHelp() = 0;`, `/* In Task4Answ */ int getHelp override { return help; }`

Comment: Is there any possibility to make tablica as an array of Tasks and get access to a field from class, which is inheriting from Task ?

Comment: @DarekD Your options are either: Make `tablica` an array of concrete `Task4Answ`s, or hoist `help` out to be part of the interface for `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
tablica[i]=new Task4Answ("0",0,0);
```

Although you have called the `Task4Answ` constructor, you are also assigning the memory address returned by `new` to a `Task` pointer. Effectively, you have casted the `Task4Answ` pointer to a `Task` pointer. On the lines that follow, C++ only sees `tablica[i]` as a reference to a `Task` pointer. You need to change:

```
protected:
    Task *tablica[10];
    TaskCollection T1;
```

...to this:

```
protected:
    Task4Answ *tablica[10]; // Task was changed to Task4Answ
    TaskCollection T1;
```

That should allow C++ to see `tablica` as an array of `Task4Answ` pointers instead of `Task` pointers.

Edit: it looks like `help` is also private. You will have to change `help` to public or add `TaskCollection::TaskCollection()` as a friend. Otherwise, C++ will not let you get or set `help`.

Edit: the OP added that `tablica[i]` might contain instances of other classes that inherit from `Task`. In that case, you could do something like this:

```
void Generuj()
{
        if(T1.collection[x]->id_pyt==1)
        {
            Task4Answ* newTask = new Task4Answ("0",0,0);
            newTask->contents=T1.collection[x]->contents;
            newTask->id_pyt=T1.collection[x]->id_pyt;
            newTask->nr_pyt=T1.collection[x]->nr_pyt;
            newTask->help=T1.collection[x]->help; // You will still have to change this from being private.
            tablica[i] = newTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Later on, in order to access `help`, you will need to implement some sort of way of checking whether `tablica[i]` is a `Task4Answ` and not an instance of some other class that inherits from `Task`, perhaps by implementing a method in `Task` named `IsTask4Answ` that returns `false` in `Task` but is overridden to return `True` in `Task4Answ`. You can then cast the pointer back to `Task4Answ` with something like the `static_cast` operator. In other words:

```
// Add these functions to the class definitions:
virtual bool Task::IsTask4Answ() const {
    return false;
}
bool Task4Answ::IsTask4Answ() const override {
    return true;
}
// Later, you can do this:
if(tablica[i].IsTask4Answ()){
    Task4Answ* t = static_cast<Task4Answ*>(tablica[i]);
    t->help; // Again, you'll have to change this from being private.
}
```

Although I suggest figuring out a different data structure where you do not need to do any casting, this will allow you to access `help`.

Do note the `virtual` keyword in the first function above; it allows the function to be dynamically bound, which means that the code will check whether to call `Task::IsTask4Answ()` or `Task4Answ::IsTask4Answ()` at runtime instead of at compile time.

Comment: The thing is i didnt write the whole code in topic, cause there are 4 classes which are inheriting from Task, they have the same contents. And i have to make an array of objects of those 4 classes.

Comment: @DarekD Ah, that changes things. I have edited my answer to cover that territory. If it is possible to redo your data structures to not require casting, however, that is usually way easier to read and follow.

Comment: Thank you very much bro, now i see my mistakes. Will change some data structure to not do that castings. One more time much thanks !

Comment: In order to be able to properly deep-copy heterogeneous arrays of pointers to a base class, you'll need to add something like `std::unique_ptr<Task> clone() const` to the base `Task` class (and also make the destructor `Task::~Task()` virtual).  Then, override it in each subclass.  Even if you know now that all the derived classes have the same contents, it's not a good idea to rely on that continuing to hold in the future as you extend the class hierarchy.  ...And also, incidentally, you should usually prefer using `std::vector` or `std::array` over raw C-style arrays.